# Building a json structure for aggregate query dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I want to build a query matching the fields that has data in them.

I tried this:

```
var matchStr = {};
if (received.user) {
    matchStr = { "_id":   { "$regex": received.user,  "$options": "i" } };
}
if (received.name) {
    matchStr += { "name":   { "$regex": received.name,  "$options": "i" } };
}
if (received.phone) {
    matchStr += { "phone":   { "$regex": received.phone,  "$options": "i" } };
}

usersTable.aggregate([
{
    $match: { matchStr }
}, etc...
```

I tried this:

```
var matchStr = [];
if (received.user) {
    matchStr.push( { "_id":   { "$regex": received.user,  "$options": "i" } } );
}
if (received.name) {
    matchStr.push( { "name":   { "$regex": received.name,  "$options": "i" } } );
}
if (received.phone) {
    matchStr.push( { "phone":   { "$regex": received.phone,  "$options": "i" } } );
}       

usersTable.aggregate([
{
    $match: { matchStr }
}, etc...
```

None of them works.

Is there really no smart way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use an array inside `$match`, the correct way is to use an object and assign to it:

```
var matchStr = {};
if (received.user) {
    matchStr["_id"] = { "$regex": received.user,  "$options": "i" };
}
//etc...   

usersTable.aggregate([
{
   $match: matchStr
}, 
//etc...
```

Comment: Thanks Nick - so does this mean I can still use `$match: { matchStr }` ? -  Im gonna try it at once

Comment: I've updated my answer, you need to pass it directly, `$match: matchStr`

Comment: PERFECT!!! Thanks so much Nick!!! - I have to stop thinking of mongodb aggregates as strings (my background is MsSql and Oracle hehe). Mongo aggregate is objects!!  Everything works now.